# Front-end major break after upgrade PHP 8.0

Tags: php, fatal-error

I just got this major error message on the front-end (Back-end is working). I already tried:

- Disable all plugins. (No effect)
- Change theme for a default theme. (Working fine).
- Change for a third party theme - Astra and Hello Elementor - (Working fine).

**UPDATE**
As  @Jacob Peattie and @Tom J Nowell mentioned. It's a bug on "wp_head".

I disabled the 'heads' on the layout and it's loading. After some test, I've discovered that if I comment 'wp_head( )' function, the page loads.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "printStyle" not found or invalid function name in /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:307 

Stack trace: 
#0 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #1 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#2 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/general-template.php(3042): do_action('wp_head') 
#3 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-content/themes/bfr/header-home.php(27): wp_head() 
#4 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/template.php(770): require_once('/nas/content/li...') 
#5 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/template.php(716): load_template('/nas/content/li...', true, Array) 
#6 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array) 
#7 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-content/themes/bfr/index.php(3): get_header('home') 
#8 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/nas/content/li...') 
#9 /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/nas/content/li...') 
#10 /nas/content/live/mysite/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...') 
#11 {main} thrown in /nas/content/live/mysite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307
```

Comment: Well your own testing shows that the theme is responsible, and I can see `/themes/bfr/header-home.php` in the stack trace. Have you contacted the theme author for support?

Comment: Jacobs right, it looks like a bug in the `bfr` theme, that was probably causing PHP notices but with the upgrade to 8.0 is now causing fatal errors. Downgrade PHP or switch to another theme and wait until they release an update that's 8.0 compatible

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie for the tip!! - Now I'm facing another issue, when I comment 'wp_head( )' function, the page loads (without all styling and other jQuery scripts).

Comment: `wp_head()` is necessary, as you've discovered. Look instead for something trying to hook `printStyle` to the [`wp_head` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/). It'll probably look like `add_action( 'wp_head', 'printStyle' );` or maybe `add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'printStyle' ) );`.